# Steps to make another copy of Laravel 5.2 project in htdocs

Tags: laravel, project

I am using Laravel 5.2 I have a Laravel project in a folder called project1 in my local server. I have created a new folder called project2 and have pasted all the content from project1 folder and change database name in database.php file. What else changes I have to do to make project2 work. Project2 is still referring to old database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tell us what error you are receiving.

Comment: Did you do: php artisan cache:clear
and eventually php artisan config:clear
and a last line of rescue you can manually remove the cached data

Comment: You have to change the database configuration in `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the database configurations on `config/database.php` and `.env` file on root.
2. Run composer update `php composer.phar update`

Now you can run `project2`